# sharepoint 2013 publish website other than 80 port not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

I have created sharepoint 2013 publish website on 3333 port now i want to alternate access mapping for this site with domain abc.com . Is there any ways to do this ? I want access my website with abc.com from outside.

Answer (score 0):

If abc.com is a register DNS and point to the correct web front end then yes you will access it.please make sure

- Abc.com is dns and point to your wfe.
- in AAM settings default URL should be abc.com
- also make firewall orAV is not blocking that port

Comment: and point to your wife ?

Comment: It was typo,as I posted from iPhone...just corrected

Comment: I have published sharepoint website with http://webapp:3333 which set as default in aam and now how can I set abc.com as default too.

Comment: edit the public URL and replace it with abc.com